# jQuery.insertBefore is not respecting the line break

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple html with a div limited by width. Inside I have many `span` tags that are configured with `nowrap`. My css:

```
.content {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.adder {
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.added {
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

And my html:

```
<div class="content">
    <span class="added">A text just a little large 1.</span>
    <span class="added">A text just a little large 2.</span>
    <span class="added">A text just a little large 3.</span>
    <span class="added">A text just a little large 4.</span>
    <span class="added">A text just a little large 5.</span>
    <span class="adder">Add</span>
</div>
```

As expected, the text is broken when there is no more space in the line to be placed. Then the entire `span` is rendered on the next line. Now I added some javascript code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".adder").click(function() {
        $(document.createElement("span"))
            .addClass("added")
            .html("A custom text to be add,")
            .insertBefore(this);
    });
});
```

So, now a new `span` is placed before the `Add` text for every time I click on `Add`.

But the problem is this, when I click a few more times in the `Add`, there comes a point where the end of the line size is reached, but rather to break the line as the other part of the text does, the new `span` is simply rendered in the same line overlapping the edge of the `div`.

Why this happen? How to avoid it?

I'm testing this page in `Google Chrome 42.0.2311.135`.
The whole html can be viewed in [jsfinddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonataspiazzi/eL07r2um/).

Comment: Why are you posting unreadable compacted HTML? I'd suggest you post a link to a working jsFiddle so folks can see the exact issue you're talking about and perhaps play with what is causing the problem.

Comment: but I don't know any site that allow me post a html to I reference here. Do you have a site, repository, suggestion?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xLs9trq2/

Comment: You can just put the HTML in your actual question, formatted to be readable rather than compacted onto one line.  No external site needed just to share the HTML.  In fact, StackOverflow does not want the only reference to data that is important to the question to be an external link.  SO wants that data in the actual question.  I'm just saying you should format it to be readable, not one giant line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `insertBefore` there is no space added between yoru elements.  Simply add a space yourself and they will wrap as you expect:

```
$(function() {
    $(".adder").click(function() {
        $(document.createElement("span"))
            .addClass("added")
            .html("A custom text to be add,")
            .insertBefore(this)
            .after(" ");  // add a single space
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gtoh8hzp/

Answer (score 4):

Your original list of "added" `<span>` elements have whitespace between them. The ones you add with the JavaScript code don't.  Therefore, the browser can't insert line breaks between them — it will only do that at whitespace boundaries.

You can fix that in a few different ways; one simple way is to add this to your "click" handler:

```
$("<span/>", { text: " " }).insertBefore(this);
```

Another way to fix it is with pure CSS:

```
.added::after {
  white-space: normal;
  content: "\00200B";
}
```

No JavaScript changes would be necessary with that approach.

Comment: your answer is right too, but the other guy answer before. +1 for that.